# Annoying video playback in chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video, graphics-card

It appears that any video (i.e. Youtube, Vimeo) that is played in Chrome has that annoying artefact - I don't know a correct terminology for it, it looks like in the upper third of the screen I can see the border between a previous and a current frame. It is very noticeable if there is some substantial movement in the video, and almost not noticeable if the movement is slow.

I cannot see that artefact in IE, at least not to that extent.

I tried to disable Flash in chrome://plugins, didn't help.

I don't know if it is related, but I see the same thing in the Windows interface, for example when I move a window around the screen fast.

I have:

- Windows 7 x64
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 980Ti G1 Gaming with version 355.98 Driver
- Chrome Version 45.0.2454.99 m

Comment: Sounds like video tearing, usually caused by vertical sync problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing.  What type of monitors do you have, do they have particularly odd refresh rates?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Screen tearing, now I know how to call it, thanks. I have LG 24' monitors with 60 Hz refresh rate

Answer (score 3):

There might be a bug with the video driver. You could try turning off hardware acceleration. Open a new tab and enter this address: chrome://settings/search#acceleration. Uncheck `Use hardware acceleration when available`

Comment: Can you include the relevant information here please? That link may change or disappear which would make the answer not very useful. Thanks!

Comment: "Can you include the relevant information here please? That link may change or disappear which would make the answer not very useful. Thanks!" Done!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. It changed things a bit though - now the tearing border can be anywhere in the frame, before it position was more or less constant.